# jQuery EasyUI -ComboGrid Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I wnat to show to display grid in combo box using jquery easy ui plugin with asp.net mvc. But I took that error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).combogrid is not a function". Where is the error?

## My View Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ComboGrid - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/easyui.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/icon.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/demo.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.combogrid.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#cc').combogrid({
                panelWidth: 450,
                value: '006',

                idField: 'code',
                textField: 'name',
                url: 'datagrid_data.json',
                columns: [[
                    { field: 'code', title: 'Code', width: 60 },
                    { field: 'name', title: 'Name', width: 100 },
                    { field: 'addr', title: 'Address', width: 120 },
                    { field: 'col4', title: 'Col41', width: 100 }
                ]]
            });
        });
        function reload() {
            $('#cc').combogrid('grid').datagrid('reload');
        }
        function setValue() {
            $('#cc').combogrid('setValue', '002');
        }
        function getValue() {
            var val = $('#cc').combogrid('getValue');
            alert(val);
        }
        function disable() {
            $('#cc').combogrid('disable');
        }
        function enable() {
            $('#cc').combogrid('enable');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>ComboGrid</h2>
    <div class="demo-info">
        <div class="demo-tip icon-tip"></div>
        <div>Click the right arrow button to show the datagrid.</div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin:10px 0;">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="reload()">Reload</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="setValue()">SetValue</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="getValue()">GetValue</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="disable()">Disable</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="enable()">Enable</a>
    </div>
    <select id="cc" name="dept" style="width:250px;"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.combogrid.js"></script>
```

because `jquery.easyui.min.js` includes `combogrid` function.